# Flex 4.6 BusyIndicator Missing

Tags: apache-flex, busyindicator

> ```
>   <fx:Declarations>
>   </fx:Declarations>
>
>   <s:BusyIndicator>
>   </s:BusyIndicator>
> ```

Error message is => Could not resolve {} to a component implementation.

Any idea how to resolve this?

I am using Flex SDK 4.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[BusyIndicator](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/BusyIndicator.html) is a mobile-only component. If you're using FlashBuilder, make sure your project is a mobile project. In any case, you have to make sure that **mobilecomponents.swc** is on the classpath.

If you want to use this component in a non-mobile project, I would think you could simply add the mobilecomponents.swc to the build path, and you should be able to use it. Here's how you can [add a library to the build path manually in FlashBuilder](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flashbuilder/using/WSe4e4b720da9dedb524b8220812e5611f28f-7fef.html#WSe4e4b720da9dedb524b8220812e5611f28f-7fdc).

And here's another article on using mobile components in web projects: http://www.riagora.com/2011/08/flex-mobile-in-the-browser/